# Search common indexes of multiple 2D matrix in Matlab under specific constraints

Tags: matlab, matrix, mathematical-optimization

I have three real-valued 2D matrices **A**, **B**, **C** that are function of two vectors **q** (length *N*) and **w** (length *M*). As a result, all the matrices are *N* X *M*. Due to the complexity of the problem, I do not know whether those functions are convex and may have several local maxima/minima.

In Matlab, to find the indexes of the values in the three matrices that meet some given conditions (e.g., bigger that a real value *a*, *b*, or *c*),  I use

```
[q_idxs, w_idxs] = find( (A > a) & (B > b) & (C > c) );
```

Using those indexes, I find the values of **q** and **w** so that the matrices meet the constraints.

However, those constraints might be quite restrictive.
I now would like to find the indexes of the points that are closest to the maxima and minima values of the matrices. Something like

```
[q_idxs, w_idxs] = findClosestIdx(A, max(A),B, max(B),C, min(C) );
```

The would find the closest points to the maximum of A, the maximum of B, and the minimum of C.
I guess this would be a problem of constrained optimisation, but I am not familiar with the topic.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Curious if the solution provided here worked for you.

Comment: The suggested solution is very interesting and provides with what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, Divakar. Very helpful indeed.

Comment: Great! Good to hear from you finally :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way I have understood your question, let me make some assumptions and present the code.

Assuming you meant, finding points in `A` that are closest to the maximum of `A`, similarly for `B` and finding points in `C` that are closest to the minimum of `C` and that you would like to have a common threshold to set the "closeness" which will be valid across all those three closeness conditions for `A`, `B` and `C`, you may try this -

```
%// th is the common threshold of "closeness" for A, B and C

condmat = ((max(A(:))-A) <th) & ((max(B(:))-B) <th) & ((C-min(C(:))) <th)
[q_idxs, w_idxs] = find(condmat)
```